# running a script after svn up in windows if there were incoming changes

Tags: windows, svn

My project is divided into bunch of subprojects . I want to automate the process of getting all the changes from svn, building and deploying it . So i I want to build and deploy a project only if there were incoming changes from svn . 
Is there a way to automate this ? Note that I am using a windows machine ( unfortunately )

Comment: Why you can't run the build script on the server? Possibly you should run a Windows svn server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SVN's post-commit hook feature.

[This link](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/244.cfm) explains how to send email after someone commits to the repository.

EDIT: Looks like you need a script in the local machine. What you can do is to create a batch file that runs the `svn update` and checks whether there are modified files.

To see whether there are modified files, you can check the first character of the output of `svn update` whether it begins with A (file added), D (file deleted), U (file updated), or G (file merged). I intentionally exclude the line that begins with C (conflict) because updates with conflicts (most likely) will not build.

Unfortunately, I can't give you any code since I'm not familiar with batch programming.

Comment: Thanks . Looks like this a svn server feature . I want something like that locally .I want to do this on my local machine ( client)

Answer (score 0):

If you can communicate with the server, then there should be ways the server can communicate with your client/local machine. *ryanprayogo* posted a link which demonstrates how to send email from the `post-commit` hook. So you can run a script on your local machine which monitors a special email account and activates the build process. There are much more options of notification mechanisms.